# @wdio/cli:launcher: No specs found to run, exiting with failure

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am having an issue being able to run my first test in webdriver-IO. When running the test in terminal, I receive an error message stating no specs has been found to run.

Error log
This is the full error message (ERROR @wdio/cli:launcher: No specs found to run, exiting with failure)

Node version: v18.16.1
[specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aTtx.png)
[Terminal error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rLoT.png)